# Why my dropdown list don't fill up textboxes?

Tags: c#, database, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdownlist item named `IsAuthor`. It do not fill my textboxes by retrieving value from tblnewgroup table. Where is the problem I can not understand and it do not show any error please help me

```
protected void lstAuthor_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string selectSQL;
    selectSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblnewgroup ";
    selectSQL += "WHERE Groupno='" + lstAuthor.SelectedItem.Value + "'";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSQL, con);
    SqlDataReader reader;

try
{
    con.Open();
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    reader.Read();

    txtGn.Text = reader["Groupno"].ToString();
    txtgname.Text=reader["Groupname"].ToString();
    txtsl.Text=reader["Slno"].ToString();
    txtsn.Text = reader["Subname"].ToString();

    reader.Close();
    lblResults.Text = "";
}
catch (Exception err)
{
    lblResults.Text = "Error getting author. ";
    lblResults.Text += err.Message;
}
finally
{
    con.Close();
}
```

}

I filled my drop down list by these codes..

```
private void FillAuthorList()
        {
            lstAuthor.Items.Clear();
            string selectSQL = "SELECT Groupname, Groupno FROM tblnewgroup";

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSQL, con);
            SqlDataReader reader;

            try
            {
                con.Open();
                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    ListItem newItem = new ListItem();
                    newItem.Text = reader["Groupname"].ToString();
                    newItem.Value = reader["Groupno"].ToString();
                    lstAuthor.Items.Add(newItem);
                }
                reader.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                lblResults.Text = "Error reading list of names. ";
                lblResults.Text += err.Message;
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Use  `while(reader.read()){ // code here }`

Comment: Is `Groupno` a number or text field? `

Comment: Group no is a number....@Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem :**  you are assigning single quotes to number feild `Groupno`.
**Solution :** you need to assign single quotes to `VARCHAR` Types only.

**Suggestion:** you are just assigning the values from SqlDataReader object without checking for rows.if the rows are not found then it will throw the Exeption. So i would suggest to Ceck the SqlDataReader object for any rows before assigning the values to TextBox Controls.

Try This:

```
protected void lstAuthor_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string selectSQL;
    selectSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblnewgroup ";
    selectSQL += "WHERE Groupno=" + lstAuthor.SelectedValue;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSQL, con);
    SqlDataReader reader;

try
{
    con.Open();
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if(reader.Read())
    {
    txtGn.Text = reader["Groupno"].ToString();
    txtgname.Text=reader["Groupname"].ToString();
    txtsl.Text=reader["Slno"].ToString();
    txtsn.Text = reader["Subname"].ToString();
    lblResults.Text = "Data Updated Successfully!";
    }
    else
    {
      lblResults.Text = "No Records found!";
    }
    reader.Close();

}
catch (Exception err)
{
    lblResults.Text = "Error getting author. ";
    lblResults.Text += err.Message;
}
finally
{
    con.Close();
}

}
```

Comment: small thing bro... passing ' (single quote) to numeric field do works

Comment: @MNAH: not working means? wha exactly is happening , are you getting any error?

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi it does not show any error and also nothing showing any data to my textboxes....sorry

Comment: @MNAH: use `SelectedValue` instead of `SelectedItem` in query string -try this->   `selectSQL += "WHERE Groupno=" + lstAuthor.SelectedValue;` , check my edited answer

Answer (score 1):

I assume [`SqlDataReader.Read`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method returns `boolean` value and you can use it like;

```
while(reader.Read())
{
    txtGn.Text = reader["Groupno"].ToString();
    txtgname.Text=reader["Groupname"].ToString();
    txtsl.Text=reader["Slno"].ToString();
    txtsn.Text = reader["Subname"].ToString();
}
```

Also I suspect `lstAuthor.SelectedItem.Value` is a `number` instead of a `string`. You might need to use it without using `""`.

Also using [`parameterized queries`](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) always a good choice.

```
selectSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblnewgroup WHERE Groupno = @Groupno";
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSQL, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Groupno", lstAuthor.SelectedItem.Value);
....
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're selecting on a number field, but treating it like a text field.  Modify your query to remove the single quotes:

```
selectSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblnewgroup ";
selectSQL += "WHERE Groupno=" + lstAuthor.SelectedItem.Value;
```

Also check the return value of `reader.read()`  to see if there are any records:

```
using(var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    if(reader.Read())
    {
        txtGn.Text = reader["Groupno"].ToString();
        txtgname.Text=reader["Groupname"].ToString();
        txtsl.Text=reader["Slno"].ToString();
        txtsn.Text = reader["Subname"].ToString();

    }
    else
    {
        lblResults.Text = "Author not found";
    }
}
```

Note that I've put the reader in a `using` block to ensure it is closed, even if an exception occurs.

Comment: better and clean solution

Answer (score 0):

Use following:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    txtGn.Text = reader["Groupno"].ToString();
txtgname.Text=reader["Groupname"].ToString();
txtsl.Text=reader["Slno"].ToString();
txtsn.Text = reader["Subname"].ToString();

}
```